# MySQL conditional row update based on other tables

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, database-migration

I have the following MySQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE notification
    (`id` int, `person_id` int, `rule_id` int, `account_id` int, `account_display_name` varchar(16))
;

INSERT INTO notification
    (`id`, `person_id`, `rule_id`, `account_id`, `account_display_name`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 'Muad''Dib'),
    (2, 1, 1, 2, 'Kwisatz Haderach'),
    (3, 1, 2, 2, 'Kwisatz Haderach'),
    (4, 2, 1, 3, 'Duncan'),
    (5, 2, 2, 4, 'Duncan Idaho')
;


CREATE TABLE person
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(6), `organization_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO person
    (`id`, `name`, `organization_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'paul', 1),
    (2, 'duncan', 1),
    (3, 'paul', 2),
    (4, 'duncan', 2),
    (5, 'paul', 3),
    (6, 'duncan', 3)
;


CREATE TABLE account
    (`id` int, `display_name` varchar(16), `person_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO account
    (`id`, `display_name`, `person_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Muad''Dib', 1),
    (2, 'Kwisatz Haderach', 1),
    (3, 'Duncan', 2),
    (4, 'Duncan Idaho', 2),
    (5, 'Muad''Dib', 3),
    (6, 'Kwisatz Haderach', 3),
    (7, 'Duncan', 4),
    (8, 'Duncan Idaho', 4),
    (9, 'Muad''Dib', 5),
    (10, 'Kwisatz Haderach', 5),
    (11, 'Duncan', 6),
    (12, 'Duncan Idaho', 6)
;


CREATE TABLE organization
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(17))
;

INSERT INTO organization
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'atreides'),
    (2, 'atreides_dev'),
    (3, 'atreides_research')
;


CREATE TABLE rule
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(14))
;

INSERT INTO rule
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'bug'),
    (2, 'false_positive')
;
```

Conceptually, the system in question generates a `notification` when an event occurs that is considered relevant to `person`. Whether or not a `notification` gets generated is determined by `rule` (the relation between `person` and `rule` is defined elsewhere, but that's outside the scope of this question). Every `notification` that gets generated for a `person` is specifically related to an `account` owned by that `person`, and it also contains the (denormalized) `account_display_name` of the `account`.

Notice that a `person` is also related to exactly one `organization`.

Currently, I have a set of `notifications` (with related `accounts`) for multiple `persons` in a particular `organization`. But I need to move these `notifications` to different replica `organizations` (with replica `persons` and `accounts`) based on the `rule` that caused the `notification`.

Below is an example of the type of migration I'm trying to perform.

**State of related tables**

```
person
+----+--------+-----------------+
| id |  name  | organization_id |
+----+--------+-----------------+
|  1 | paul   |               1 |
|  2 | duncan |               1 |
|  3 | paul   |               2 |
|  4 | duncan |               2 |
|  5 | paul   |               3 |
|  6 | duncan |               3 |
+----+--------+-----------------+

organization
+----+-------------------+
| id |       name        |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | atreides          |
|  2 | atreides_dev      |
|  3 | atreides_research |
+----+-------------------+

account
+----+------------------+-----------+
| id |   display_name   | person_id |
+----+------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Muad'Dib         |         1 |
|  2 | Kwisatz Haderach |         1 |
|  3 | Duncan           |         2 |
|  4 | Duncan Idaho     |         2 |
|  5 | Muad'Dib         |         3 |
|  6 | Kwisatz Haderach |         3 |
|  7 | Duncan           |         4 |
|  8 | Duncan Idaho     |         4 |
|  9 | Muad'Dib         |         5 |
| 10 | Kwisatz Haderach |         5 |
| 11 | Duncan           |         6 |
| 12 | Duncan Idaho     |         6 |
+----+------------------+-----------+

rule
+----+----------------+
| id |      name      |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | bug            |
|  2 | false_positive |
+----+----------------+
```

**Initial state of notifications**

```
+----+-----------+---------+------------+----------------------+
| id | person_id | rule_id | account_id | account_display_name |
+----+-----------+---------+------------+----------------------+
|  1 |         1 |       1 |          1 | Muad'Dib             |
|  2 |         1 |       1 |          2 | Kwisatz Haderach     |
|  3 |         1 |       2 |          2 | Kwisatz Haderach     |
|  4 |         2 |       1 |          3 | Duncan               |
|  5 |         2 |       2 |          4 | Duncan Idaho         |
+----+-----------+---------+------------+----------------------+
```

**End state of notifications**

```
+----+-----------+---------+------------+----------------------+
| id | person_id | rule_id | account_id | account_display_name |
+----+-----------+---------+------------+----------------------+
|  1 |         3 |       1 |          5 | Muad'Dib             |
|  2 |         3 |       1 |          6 | Kwisatz Haderach     |
|  3 |         5 |       2 |         10 | Kwisatz Haderach     |
|  4 |         4 |       1 |          7 | Duncan               |
|  5 |         6 |       2 |         12 | Duncan Idaho         |
+----+-----------+---------+------------+----------------------+
```

As you can see, the `person_id` and `account_id` of the `notifications` have been updated based on the `notification's` `rule_id`. Specifically:

- Every `notification` generated by the `bug` `rule` (ID 1) was moved to the corresponding `person` and `account` replicas in the `atreides_dev` `organization` (ID 2).
- Every `notification` generated by the `false_positive` `rule` (ID 2) was moved to the corresponding `person` and `account` replicas in the `atreides_research` `organization` (ID 3).

I've written a SQL query that (I believe) selects the correct `notification.person_id` and `notification.account_id` based on `notification.rule_id`, but I'm unsure of the best way to use this in an UPDATE statement, such that every `notification` gets updated correctly.

Here is the SELECT:

```
select p_replica.id, acc_replica.id as account_id
from (select p.name, person_id, rule_id, account_id, account_display_name from notification n
inner join person p
on n.person_id = p.id
where p.organization_id = 1
and n.rule_id in (1)) as notifications
 inner join person p_replica
 on p_replica.name = notifications.name
 and p_replica.organization_id = 2
 inner join account acc_replica
 on acc_replica.person_id = p_replica.id
 and acc_replica.display_name = notifications.account_display_name;
```

Notice that the SELECT specifies an origin `organization` (ID 1), a destination `organization` (ID 2), and a `rule` whose `notifications` need to be migrated. Recall that this is based on a mapping of `rule` to destination `organization`. In other words, selecting all updated `notifications` would require one execution of this query per mapping of `rule` -> `organization`.

What would an UPDATE query for performing this migration look like?

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c71765/6) to play around with.

Comment: Why not provide the inserts and/or fiddle to go with the above?

Comment: Good idea @Strawberry, added!